# Uniform convergence and maximum of an absolute difference

Tags: analysis

I am trying to prove that: Consider the sequence  $a_n = \sup_{x\in S}|f_n(x) - f(x)|$. Then  $f_n$  converges to  $f$  uniformly if and only if  $a_n$  tends to $0$. But I can't prove that if  $f_n$  converges to  $f$  uniformly, then $a_n$  tends to $0$. I have not been able to go from $|f_n(x) - f(x)|<\epsilon$ to $\sup_{x\in S}|f_n(x) - f(x)|<\epsilon$ using the inequalities in the supposition. How do I do this in detail using the inequalities in the supposition?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly.

Then for all $\epsilon>0$,  there exists an  $N$ such that for all $x \in S$ and all $n >N$, $|f_n(x) -f(x)|< \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

Then $|f_n(x) -f(x)|$ is bounded above by $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ for all $x$.

Suppose $c_n = \sup_\limits{x\in S}\{|f_n(x) -f(x)|\}$. Then $c_n$ is the least upper bound of the set above, so $c_n \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2} < \epsilon$.

So there exists an $N$ such that for all $n>N$, $c_n < \epsilon$.

Comment: What does c stand for? Is it the limit of csubn?

Comment: @Eric Brown Thought I edited out all references to $c$, that's supposed to be $c_n$.

Comment: Why can't csubn be equal to epsilon?

Comment: @eric brown Think it through first.

Comment: GREAT! That answers my question. One addition needs to be made. |fn(x)−f(x)| is bounded above by ϵ/2 for all x.

Answer (score 0):

> I have not been able to go from $|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$ to
>   $\sup_{x \in S}|f_n(x) - f(x)|< \epsilon$ using the inequalities...

It may help to ask yourself the question: in the first inequality above, what is $x$? Is it a specific $x$? Or are you missing a qualifier on $x$, such as "for all $x$ in..." For that matter, what is $n$?

(To answer these questions, consult the definition of uniform convergence. Then the answer to your problem should be right in front of you.)

Answer (score 0):

The fact that $ f_{n} $ converges uniformly to $ f $ implies that given $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $ n_{0}\in \mathbb {N}$ such that for all $ x \in S $, $|f_{n}(x)-f (x)|<\frac {\varepsilon}{2} $ it inmediately follows that $sup \{|f_{n}(x)-f (x)|:x\in S\}\leq \frac {\varepsilon}{2} <\varepsilon$

Comment: Let $\epsilon = 1$, $f_n = x^n$ and let our interval be $(0,1)$.  $|f_n(x) - f(x)|<1$ but $\sup_{x \in S} |f_n(x) - f(x)| = 1$ for all $n$.

Comment: True! Thank you! I edited there!